# Signing Token Verification Transactions on Etherscan Using Safe Multisig

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have a question regarding the use of Safe multisig on Etherscan. Is it possible to sign token verification transactions on Etherscan using a Safe multisig? To provide some context, I am trying to sign token contract ownership on Etherscan where the contract owner is designated as a multisig address. The aim is to verify that I am the legitimate owner of the token.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a support question to a private, for-profit, closed source product and should be answered by the support desk of Etherscan, not a public forum.

Comment: Can you provide more context? Who are you trying to prove ownership to? What exactly is your token contract? If your token contract is an ERC20/ERC721 then you can use `balanceOf` or `ownerOf` to prove an address owns an amount/certain token.